# Cross domain Iframe localStorage on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, iframe, local-storage, cross-domain

I am working on a solution for matching click and sale.

User clicks on a link on the domain a.com and will be redirected to the domain track.domain.com/click.php

```
-> here in click.php I am storing a variable with localStorage.setItem('test', 1);
-> redirect the user to b.com
```

On b.com on the thank you page there is a javascript loaded from track.domain.com/track.js for example, in which:

```
-> I am adding an iframe to the body of b.com/thankyou.php with track.domain.com/tracking.php
-> in tracking.php I am getting the value from the local storage localStorage.getItem('test').
```

On all browsers and phones except iPhone this solution works fine. Somehow the iPhone is overriding the origin of the frame and I can not check the localStorage for my key.

Does anyone has a good solution for this?

Comment: Use a cookie instead? Or you can use [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the 2 windows

Comment: Cookie doesn't work in this case for iphone. But I have only one window, because I am redirecting from page a -> track -> b .. this is only one window.

Comment: But you said there was an iframe which makes it 2 windows in page. Iframe is a separate window from main page window